# Change blockquotes when selecting faces

Tags: javascript

I have bunch of code already written ([JS fiddle project](http://jsfiddle.net/erikblomqvist/999ab/)) and I'm almost done, but I need some kind toggle thing i JS when you click a person's face, then the quote (scroll down at the result if you can't see it) will change to that person's quote.

I've already got a switch in the JS with this part:

```
$(function() {
    var $profiles = $("#profile1, #profile2, #profile3, #profile4, #profile5, #profile6, #profile7, #profile8, #profile9, #profile10, #profile11");
    $profiles.click(function(e) {
        $profiles.removeClass("focused");
        $(this).addClass("focused");
    });
});
```

but I need to combine it with the quotes somehow.

If you really don't want to help me out with specific, I'd be just happy with just pseudo code or help on how to think. I've been sitting with this piece for way too long now to be able to think straight.

What would you recommend?

Cheers all, you guys rock!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved your problem like this:

```
$profiles.click(function(e) {
    var profileNr = parseInt($(this).attr("id").substring(7));
    $profiles.removeClass("focused");
    $(this).addClass("focused");
    $(".thequote .show").removeClass("show");
    $(".thequote blockquote").eq(profileNr-1).find("p").addClass("show");
});
```

It extracts the index of the quote from the profile number and then selects the appropriate quote with jQuery eq(). I updated your JS Fiddle as well and tested that it works.

Comment: Dude, that was totally killer! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

You have to have some kind of reference in your blockquote, for example a data attribute which indicates to which profile the quote belongs. For example:

```
<blockquote data-profileid="profile8">
    <p>
        "Sist är starkast... eller något sånt."
    </p>
</blockquote>
```

Then in the onclick function, show the blockquote with the data attribute that matches the clicked id. You can get the clicked id like this:

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
```